# Angular animation of parent div causes content of material tab not to be visible after animation is finished

Tags: angular, animation, angular-material, angular-animations, mat-tab

I have an angular animation on a div. Inside of the div I have a material tab component. When I click on one of the tabs as the div is animating into the page, the content of the tab disappears once the animation of the div is finished.

Here is a stackblitz to demonstrate my issue. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5papgq

Steps to reproduce.

1. Click on one of the tabs to change tabs as the div containing the tabs are fading into the page.
2. Wait for all the tabs to finish animating into the page.
3. Watch the tab content disappear.

Is this a problem with my animation or is it an issue with the tab component itself?

Comment: did you submit this issue to the https://github.com/angular/components/issues?